# Hide and show view in swift 4.2 xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to iOS app development. i have created the view like below.[image]

and i am reusing the same view in other screen. so that screen dont need the "ss" Initials. so i have hidden than programmatically.like below.
[image]

here i am facing the unwanted spacing issue on second screen.

What i want is, when the "SS" initials hidden, the name and subject need to come to the left aligned. i don't know what content need to give for google it. guys please give some keyword to find solution or please give some solution to it.

Comment: have you created this view programmatically or through the storyboard?

Comment: yes i have created it storyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UIStackView` for this problem.

let us call everything but the `UIImageView` is the RHS and the `UIImageView` is the LHS

place them in a vertical `UIStackView` and when you hide the `UIImageView` it should automatically remove that spacing and shift the content to fill the view.

If you haven't seen them yet I recommend [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2198310-uistackview-tutorial-for-ios-introducing-stack-views) tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use `stackViews` you can physically move the label by "animating" it or moving its frame.

```
self.labelToMove.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
```

Call this line with the desired position wherever you programatically "hide" the image view.

you can move it back by doing the same thing when you programmatically "unhide" the initials image

Comment: isn't he have to do that for everything he needs to move?

Comment: @MohmmadS if he uses stack view as you suggested he wouldnt have to do this

Comment: it is in UITableView Cell.how to give x,y with and height?

Comment: @Noorul you need to give it x and y relative to your table view cell. In the storyboard you are able to physically check the x and y coordinates. Remember to use the x and y positions within the table view cell. Use the storyboard to check

Comment: @JulianSilvestri your answer is technically correct but I think its too much headache personally and could be more complex and easily misused by some. 
Noorul you can use the cell bounds as a reference for X Y

Comment: @MohmmadS i agree with you, I am just providing another way to solve his problem. Personally implementing a stackview would be the best solution as you suggested

Comment: @JulianSilvestri its good answer by the way, and correct if the case was specified for a single component to move I will even mark that for my self in the future ^_^

Comment: @JulianSilvestri i have added the following code in cellForRowAt function of TableView.it is not working.

Comment: @JulianSilvestri.   cell.line.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:cell.btnDelete.frame.maxY, width: cell.line.frame.width , height: 1 )

Comment: my design has two buttons below to btnDelete. those two buttons will be visible on some condition. i want to set the line below to the delete button when those two buttons hidden. it is not working.

Comment: ping me if you need more explaination

Comment: @Noorul we should go into private discussion. I need more context

Comment: yes we do. how to do private chat? u need skype id or something else